# Is there a replacement for OnEnable() method?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a custom EditorWindow. And I have a bunch of classes having `RectOffset` property. These are regular classes, not inherited from `ScriptableObject` or `Monobehaviour`.

I serialize and deserialize them. When I deserialize, I instantiate them dynamically with `Activator.CreateInstance(Type, Object[]);`, e.g.:

```
public void OnAfterDeserialize() {
    Vector2 dropPosition = new Vector2(10, 10);
    Control child = (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Button), dropPosition);
    child.Name = child.InitName;
    TestRectOffset =  new RectOffset(0, 0, 0, 0); 
}
```

But in this case *Unity3d* gives me an error that I have to use `OnEnable()` for `RectOffset`.

> set_left is not allowed to be called during serialization, call it
>   from OnEnable instead.
>   See "Script Serialization" page in the Unity Manual for further details.
>   UnityEngine.RectOffset:.ctor(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)

Of course, I don't have this method. My classes will have much more than one property which must get value in `OnEnable`, but it's not possible, because they're instantiating dynamically.

What should I do to emulate `OnEnable` behavior? How to instantiate an object with `Activator.CreateInstance` without errors?

Comment: Can't you broadcast an OnEnable message and catch it in your classes?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I made my own very simplified class at the moment and it works:

```
[Serializable]
public class RectOffsetSeralizable {
    public int Top { get; set; }
    public int Left { get; set; }
    public int Right { get; set; }
    public int Bottom { get; set; }

    public RectOffsetSeralizable() : this(0, 0, 0, 0) { }

    public RectOffsetSeralizable(RectOffset rectOffset) {
        Top = rectOffset.top;
        Bottom = rectOffset.bottom;
        Left = rectOffset.left;
        Right = rectOffset.right;
    }


    public RectOffsetSeralizable(int left, int right, int top, int bottom) {
        Top = top;
        Bottom = bottom;
        Left = left;
        Right = right;
    }


    public RectOffset ToRectOffset() {
        return new RectOffset(Left, Right, Top, Bottom);
    }


    public override string ToString() {
        return $"RectOffset (l:{Left} r:{Right} t:{Top} b:{Bottom})";
    }
}
```

But if I will use another built-in *Unity* classes which require to be initialized in **OnEnable()** method - I will have to make more and more surplus classes for my purposes